# Php mail function issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to send a email to user after successfully register. So that following is my .php code.

```
$to = $email;                       
$subject = "Signup | Verification";
$message = "Congratulation $f_name $l_name you have been successfully registered. Please 
click the link to active your account.\r\n";
$message .= "http://www.maaks.fr/hotel/verify.php?email=$email&hash=$hash\r\n";

$from = "noreply@yoursite.com";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-rype: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding; 7bit\r\n";
$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";

$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);                   
if($sentmail)
{
header("Location: thankyou.php?member=successfully");
exit();
}
```

It doesn't sent a email to the user. I checked it that if **$sentmail** is ok then It's go **thankyou** page. But interesting matter is that it's go to **thankyou** page without sent a email.

Is there anything i forgot?

Comment: the mail function doesn't return true when the mail is send. It returns true when your mail has been given to your mail delivery system, whichever one that is. Meaning that the return value you get doesn't say that it has been send, but that the send procedure has started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function returns `true` if the message was accepted for delivery, it doesn't mean the message will be delivered.

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

Your message is probably being blocked by the recipients spam filter or going straight to the junk folder.

Comment: I checked it but can't find any email. Can you tell me what's the possible cause?

Comment: Try different recipients from different email providers, try gmail, hotmail, yahoo etc etc to see if any get through.

Comment: It's almost certainly being blocked as spam because the keyword `Congratulation` along with a link looks very spammy.

Comment: try running it at home on your local machine, install XAMPP or some equivalent and send your email message via localhost to a localhost email adress. Bypasses spam filters etc, then you can check whether it is a spam filter or that your code is not working. On top of that you can easily see your mail server logs allowing your to do some more digging!

Answer (score 0):

There is one minor typo in your email message but I don't think it will solve your problem.

You have a Content-rype specified, you should change that to Content-type...

But again I don't think that will solve your problem.